# Delete specific files in directory using C#

Tags: c#

There are many .bmp files present in my C:\TEMP directory.

I am using following code to delete all .bmp file in my C:\TEMP directory but somehow its not working as I expect. Can anyone help me in this?

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\TEMP\");
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    if (filePath.Contains(".bmp"))
        File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

I have already checked that .bmp file and the directory has no read only attribute

Comment: Tip: Use the searchPattern argument in Directory.GetFiles to only get bitmaps. (e.g. "*.bmp") See [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx)

Comment: Are you running app manually under your user account, do you have access to delete files from C:\Temp?  Also, are any of the files in use when your trying to delete them.  What type of results / errors are you seeing when you try to delete the files ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For starters, GetFiles has an overload which takes a search pattern http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx so you can do:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TEMP\", "*.bmp");
```

Edit: For the case of deleting all .bmp files in TEMP:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\TEMP\", "*.bmp");
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
```

This deletes all .bmp files in the folder but does not access subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

Should also use .EndsWith instead of .Contains

Answer (score -1):

You Could write below code in fast way:

```
    string[] t = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "*.pdf");
    Array.ForEach(t, File.Delete);
```

or For Text Files:

```
    string[] t = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "*.txt");
    Array.ForEach(t, File.Delete);
```

So, You could write code for all extension and all directories.